# Cannot render Iframe in Landscape mode

Tags: css, frame

Trying to figure out why this frame http://www.kicks.se/#take-your-pick

Will not render on an Ipad in landscape mode

The css that I can see is

```
}
.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item,
.embed-responsive iframe,
.embed-responsive embed,
.embed-responsive object,
.embed-responsive video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 0;
}
```

Any ideas on how this can be expanded to be shown the entire frame? I am going mad looking at it!

Comment: Seems to render fine in chrome dev tools. What is the issue? you're not being clear which "frame" is not rendering. are you talking about an iframe? post the html.

Comment: Here is the page source view-source:http://www.kicks.se/#take-your-pick it renders fine but viewing in a landscape view on an Ipad and enlarging the product selection frame it does not allow to scroll horizontal or vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends if you set your width/height depending on the parent container. The idea to match the parent device's height and width is there in the OP code. But this issue may also depend on browsers AND/OR padding issues. This example represents this technique [here](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html).

HTML:

```
<div class='box'>
<div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 1:1</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    width:    50%; /* desired width */
}

.box:before {
    content:     "";
    display:     block;
    padding-top: 100%; /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.content {
    position: absolute;
    top:      0;
    left:     0;
    bottom:   0;
    right:    0;
}

/* Other ratios - just apply the desired class to the "box" element */
.ratio2_1:before{
    padding-top: 50%;
}
.ratio1_2:before{
    padding-top: 200%;
}
.ratio4_3:before{
    padding-top: 75%;
}
.ratio16_9:before{
    padding-top: 56.25%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look